aws-sdk-client-mock not mocking DynamoDB for Javascript AWS SDK v3
I was following aws-sdk-client-mock to write a unit test case for GetCommand in javascript aws-sdk-v3. However, while following the documentation, I observed it's not mocking but its actually going to AWS and giving error like 'ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found'
The same thing was discussed here in the comments section: stack-overflow-aws-sdk-client-mock
Any help here. Thanks.
Below are the version that I'm using:
@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "3.584.0",
"@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "3.584.0",
"aws-sdk-client-mock": "^4.0.1"


Can you share snippet(s) of the unit test that's giving the error?
